# notifyDataSetChanged() method is not refreshhing listview

Tags: java, android

I am performing delete and delete all operations in my app on button click. when I click on delete button item is deleted from list view as well deleted from the server.When I click on delete all list view is not refreshing or updating at the same time.In delete all case server is updated but listview is not updated. I am using notifyDataSetChanged() method.How I can resolve this problem?

```
public void alertMessage()
            {
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        switch (which){
                            //for cancel button
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                Category_Dashboard_Page activity = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                                activity.swipeCategorylistView.closeAnimate(position);

                                break;
                            //for delete
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                Category_Dashboard_Page activity1 = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                                activity1.swipeCategorylistView.closeAnimate(position);
                                activity1.categoryList_items_obj.remove(position);
                                activity1.categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                new DeleteList().execute();
                                break;
                            //for delete all
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                                Category_Dashboard_Page activity2 = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                                activity2.swipeCategorylistView.closeAnimate(position);

                                  for(int i=0;i<categoryList_items_obj.size();i++)
                                   {
                                      Category_Dashboard_Page.CategoryList_Item category_list_item = categoryList_items_obj.get(i);
                                      System.out.println(category_list_item.getCategory_id());

                                      if(category_list_item.getCategory_id().equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
                                      {
                                          categoryList_items_obj.remove(i);
                                      }
                                   }

                               // notifyDataSetChanged();
                                System.out.println(String.valueOf(getCount()));
                                System.out.println(String.valueOf(categoryList_items_obj.size()));
                                activity2.categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                new DeleteAllList().execute();
                                break;

                        }

                    }
                };
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Are you sure?");
                builder.setMessage("You want to delete this article from all categories.")
                        .setPositiveButton("Cancel ", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Delete ", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNeutralButton("Delete all", dialogClickListener).show();

            }
```

Comment: Try `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` instead.

Comment: @Daniel K  I tried this notifyDataSetInvalidated()  same issues again

Comment: I suggest creating a method that receives new data and set's the adapter. After data has been changed call that method with proper new data.

Comment: if you are **deleting ALL**. What the need of setting adapter again ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya I needed new adapter updated value.Suppose if there is 8 items in listview ,it should be 7 items shown in list view after delete all click.

Comment: **Delete All means delete everything**.. Why it would display.. `7` items from `8` ?? After delete all it will become `0` from `8`

Comment: @jankigadhiya it i am delete by id,where the id is matched from that location particular items will be deleted from the app on button click,but I needed a method which can refresh my  listview immediately after button click

Comment: post you activity Code..!!

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16503955/ activity and http://paste.ubuntu.com/16503921/ adapter

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the corresponding adapter in onPostExecute() of DeleteList, since you are deleting the elements from the list through Aysnc task. Let me know if this solved your problem. If not, please share some more code of your project.

Comment: Could you try this: override onPostExecute() in DeleteAllList and in that call `activity1.categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @Override
                public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    Category_Dashboard_Page activity = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                    activity.categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the objects from the adapter also. Try the following code -

```
public void alertMessage()
            {
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        switch (which){
                            //for cancel button
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                Category_Dashboard_Page activity = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                                activity.swipeCategorylistView.closeAnimate(position);

                                break;
                            //for delete
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                Category_Dashboard_Page activity1 = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                                activity1.swipeCategorylistView.closeAnimate(position);
                                activity1.categoryList_items_obj.remove(position);
                                activity1.categoryAdapter.remove(position);
                                activity1.categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                new DeleteList().execute();
                                break;
                            //for delete all
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                                Category_Dashboard_Page activity2 = (Category_Dashboard_Page) context;
                                activity2.swipeCategorylistView.closeAnimate(position);

                                  for(int i=0;i<categoryList_items_obj.size();i++)
                                   {
                                      Category_Dashboard_Page.CategoryList_Item category_list_item = categoryList_items_obj.get(i);
                                      System.out.println(category_list_item.getCategory_id());

                                      if(category_list_item.getCategory_id().equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
                                      {
                                          categoryList_items_obj.remove(i);
                                          categoryAdapter.remove(i);
                                      }
                                   }

                               // notifyDataSetChanged();
                                System.out.println(String.valueOf(getCount()));
                                System.out.println(String.valueOf(categoryList_items_obj.size()));
                                activity2.categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                new DeleteAllList().execute();
                                break;

                        }

                    }
                };
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Are you sure?");
                builder.setMessage("You want to delete this article from all categories.")
                        .setPositiveButton("Cancel ", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Delete ", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNeutralButton("Delete all", dialogClickListener).show();

            }
```